# SQL Server Agent - SSIS Package - Permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, permissions

**Problem**

So I deployed this package to SSISDB and connected the SQL Agent.

My environment is: I'm on a development box with access to an FTP folder and a SQL Server. I get the files, extract the XML and move the files to an archive. I need to schedule this package to run on the same SQL Server, but when I deploy to SSISDB the package errors on a script task.

In my SSIS Package I have a script task called read file to variable. Inside this script task, I read a file like this: 
[image: script task code]

I have it deployed to SSISDB successfully and the job runs from SQL Agent. Until it hits the script task above. Then I get this error:

[image: Error]

I have updated the SQLAgentService account to use the Windows authenticated user account that was dedicated to this development account so it's using a proxy account as the SQL Agent Service account.

**Comments and what I've done**
I'm inclined to think this is permissions and I keep coming back to it.
I've shut the script task off and let the job fail somewhere else, so I know it's in the script task.
Ran package from local and from integration services, same error when deployed.
Ran package successfully from SSDT Visual Studios and everything ran fine.
Same user deploys, owns, and has permissions to the folders, solution, sql agent job, and login to sql.

The only difference is that the SQL Server is not on the development machine.

What am I missing?